# Equivalent TADOQuery.Properties in TFDQuery

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe4, firedac

What is the equivalent of `TADOQuery.Properties` in `TFDQuery` (FireDAC) in Delphi (XE7)?

I have used `QUsers.Properties['Unique Table'].Value` in a project and I'm going to convert it (from ADO components) to FireDAC components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some degree that will be TFDQuery.UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName property:
 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDBottomUpdateOptions.UpdateTableName

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `macros` in `TFDQuery` (see [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDMacro.AsRaw))

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM !TABLE_NAME_MACROS !WHERE_CLAUSE';

FDQuery.MacroByname('TABLE_NAME_MACROS').AsRaw := 'my_table';
FDQuery.MacroByname('WHERE_CLAUSE').AsRaw := 'WHERE ID = :ParamID';

FDQuery.ParamByname('ParamID').AsInteger := 1;

FDQuery1.Open;
```